# How to return Ok unit type of std::result<(), E>?

Tags: rust, unit-type

If I define a function:

```
fn f() -> Result<(), E> {
    // How to return Ok()?
}
```

How can I return the `Ok` in `std::result` with the unit type `()`?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The only value of type `()` is `()`, so just put that inside the `Ok` constructor:

```
fn f() -> Result<(), E> {
    Ok(())
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Use `Ok(())` as in

```
fn f() -> Result<(), E> {
    Ok(())
}
```