# Expected enum `std::result::Result`, found `()` when using for loop

Tags: rust

I'm tinkering with one of the examples from [the texture synth](https://github.com/EmbarkStudios/texture-synthesis) project:

```rust
use texture_synthesis as ts;

fn main() -> Result<(), ts::Error> {
    //create a new session
    let texsynth = ts::Session::builder()
        //load a single example image
        .add_example(&"imgs/1.jpg")
        .build()?;

    //generate an image
    let generated = texsynth.run(None);

    //save the image to the disk
    generated.save("out/01.jpg")
}
```

I'd like to repeat this three times using a `for` loop. This was how I thought I might do it:

```rust
use texture_synthesis as ts;

fn main() -> Result<(), ts::Error> {
    for i in 0..3 {
        let texsynth = ts::Session::builder()
            //load a single example image
            .add_example(&"imgs/1.jpg")
            .build()?;

        //generate an image
        let generated = texsynth.run(None);

        //save the image to the disk
        let index: String = i.to_string();
        let outputPath = ["out/", &index, ".jpg"].concat();
        generated.save(outputPath );
    };
}
```

However this gives me the error:

```
fn main() -> Result<(), ts::Error> {
  |    ----      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected enum `std::result::Result`, found `()`        
  |    |
  |    implicitly returns `()` as its body has no tail or `return` expression
```

This sounds like the main function is throwing an error because it's not getting a result of the type that it wants? How could I fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return Ok unit type of std::result<(), E>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27945858/how-to-return-ok-unit-type-of-stdresult-e)

Comment: See also: [Can I automatically return `Ok(())` or `None` from a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53010103/can-i-automatically-return-ok-or-none-from-a-function) and [expected enum `std::result::Result`, found `()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60020738/expected-enum-stdresultresult-found)

Comment: BTW you loop only executes twice. If you want it to run three times, you should use `for i in 1..=3` or `for i in 0..3`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `main` function is defined as `fn main() -> Result<(), ts::Error>`, which means that it *must* return a value of type `Result<(), ts::Error>`. In the original code, this is accomplished by the last line:

```
generated.save("out/01.jpg")  // Note the absence of semicolon here
```

because `generated.save` returns a value of the right type (the `return` keyword is optional for the last expression of a function in Rust, provided there is no semicolon after the expression).

In  order to fix your issue, you will need to ensure that `main` returns a value of the right type. This requires two changes:

- If a call to `generated.save` returns an error, then you should propagate the error. This is accomplished by the `?` postfix operator.
- If the loop finishes succesfully, then you should return a value that signifies that all is well. This value is `Ok(())`.

Full code:

```
use texture_synthesis as ts;

fn main() -> Result<(), ts::Error> {
    //create a new session

    for i in 1..3{
        let texsynth = ts::Session::builder()
            //load a single example image
            .add_example(&"imgs/1.jpg")
            .build()?;

        //generate an image
        let generated = texsynth.run(None);

        //save the image to the disk
        let index: String = i.to_string();
        let outputPath = ["out/", &index, ".jpg"].concat();
        generated.save(outputPath)?;
    };

    Ok(())
}
```